# FXML and Comboboxes

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Following an example on :
http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-event-handling-examples/ 
I have made a basic GUI involving a combobox. When Running my program however none of the items are being added to the combobox what so ever. I would very much appreciate it if you could point out my mistakes as to why it may not be adding the items to the combobox.
Here is a ZIP file of my project:
https://www.dropbox.com/home/Project-JavaFX
All thanks in advance!

Main.java:

```
package Main;

import Items.Item;
import Items.ItemManager;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

private static myController uj = new myController();
private static ItemManager im = new ItemManager();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    uj.initialize();
    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane mainPane = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("Main.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Main.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" stylesheets="@myStyle.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Main.myController">
   <children>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="196.0" layoutX="478.0" layoutY="-2.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="343.0" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="568.0" fitWidth="684.0" layoutX="356.0" layoutY="167.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../Pictures/builder.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="885.0" fitWidth="857.0" layoutX="629.0" layoutY="187.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="90.0">
         <image>
             <Image url="@../../../../Pictures/Uroburos-rootkit-Espionage-Russia.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="885.0" fitWidth="857.0" layoutX="-187.0" layoutY="187.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="90.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../Pictures/Uroburos-rootkit-Espionage-Russia.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Line endX="100.0" endY="400.0" layoutX="381.0" layoutY="324.0" startX="100.0" startY="-325.0" />
      <Line endX="425.0" endY="390.0" layoutX="391.0" layoutY="334.0" startX="425.0" startY="-335.0" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="stocks" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="135.0" onAction="#itemPicked" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="421.0" promptText="Please Select and Item" />
      <ScrollBar fx:id="currentP" layoutX="857.0" layoutY="108.0" onDragDetected="#getIndexC" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="400.0" />
      <Button fx:id="remove" layoutX="1007.0" layoutY="53.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteItem" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="250.0" text="Remove From Order">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <ImageView fitHeight="72.0" fitWidth="79.0" layoutX="491.0" layoutY="74.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../../../Pictures/Uroburos-rootkit-Espionage-Russia.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="491.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="311.0" text="RootKit At your Service" textAlignment="JUSTIFY">
         <font>
            <Font name="Courier New Bold Italic" size="22.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="message" layoutX="587.0" layoutY="87.0" text="&quot;Protecting&quot; your trade">
         <font>
            <Font name="Courier New Italic" size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="adding" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="81.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addItem" text="Add Item To Order">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <TextField fx:id="quantity" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="194.0" onAction="#getQuantity" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="62.0" promptText="&quot;1&quot;">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font></TextField>
      <Label layoutX="108.0" layoutY="196.0" text="Quantity" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Arial Black" size="34.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

myController.java:

```
package Main;

import Items.Item;
import Items.ItemManager;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class myController {

@FXML
private TextField quantity;

@FXML
private Button adding;

@FXML
private ScrollBar currentP;

@FXML
private Label message;

@FXML
public static ComboBox stocks = new ComboBox();

@FXML
private Button remove;

public static ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

int count = 0;

private static ItemManager im = new ItemManager();


@FXML
void itemPicked(ActionEvent event) {

}


@FXML
void getIndexC(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void deleteItem(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void addItem(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void getQuantity(ActionEvent event) {

}


public void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i = 0; i < im.inventoryItems.size(); i++) {
        options.add(im.inventoryItems.get(i).getName());
    }
    stocks.setItems(options);
}

}
```

Item.java:

```
package Items;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class Item {

//Items definitions

public static Item hammer = new Item(0, "Hammer", 5.0);
public static Item tape = new Item(1, "Tape", 3.0);
public static Item test = new Item(2, "Rare", 4.0);

protected int quantity, id;
protected String name;
protected BufferedImage sprite;
protected double price, totalPrice;

public static void updateTotalPrice(Item i) {
    i.setTotalPrice(i.getQuantity()*i.getPrice());
}

public Item (int id, String name, double price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    //quantity = 1;
    //this.totalPrice = price;
}

//Getters and Setters

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public double getTotalPrice() {
    return totalPrice;
}

public void setTotalPrice(double totalPrice) {
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}



}
```

ItemManager.java:

```
package Items;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ItemManager {

public static ArrayList<Item> inventoryItems;

public static void ItemManager() {
    inventoryItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    inventoryItems.add(Item.hammer);
    inventoryItems.add(Item.tape);
    inventoryItems.add(Item.test);
}

public Item getItemFromID(int id) {
    for (Item i : inventoryItems) {
        if (i.getId() == id) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void addItem(Item i, int quantity) {
    boolean flag = false;
    for (Item item : inventoryItems) {
        if (i.getId() == item.getId()) {
            item.setQuantity(item.getQuantity()+quantity);
            Item.updateTotalPrice(item);
            flag = true;
            //call the method to update the information box in the inventory GUI
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        inventoryItems.add(i);
        //call method for adding new info box in inventory GUI
    }
}

public void removeItem(int id) {
    for (Item item : inventoryItems) {
        if (item.getId() == this.getItemFromID(id).getId()) {
            item.setQuantity(item.getQuantity()-1);
            if (item.getQuantity() <= 0) {
                inventoryItems.remove(item);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Getters and Setters



}
```

Comment: Post your code directly in the question

Comment: @James_D done there

Comment: You're creating a new combo box, and adding items to it, instead of adding items to the one you created in the FXML. Remove the `= new ComboBox()` and, of course the keyword `static`.

Comment: @James_D that is fixed but the items are still not being added

Comment: Oh, wait. You are calling `initialize()` "by hand" on the controller. Why are you doing that? That method is called automatically when you load the FXML. You have a ton more errors that are to do with making things static that shouldn't be static. I removed every single `static` keyword except the three constants `hammer`, `tape`, and `test`, and rewrote `updateTotalPrice(Item)` as a regular instance method `public void updateTotalPrice()`. Why are you using `static` all over the place?  Apart from constants and `main()`, you should consider `static` to be for pretty advanced use only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things I recommend to change:

#### Main class

```
private static myController uj = new myController();
private static ItemManager im = new ItemManager();
```

as well as

```
uj.initialize();
```

Should be removed from the `Main` class. The controller's `initialize` method is automatically called by `FXMLLoader`. Furthermore `uj` is a different instance to the one used with your fxml. The `im` field is simply unnecessary since it's never used in the class.

#### ItemManager class

```
public static void ItemManager() {
    inventoryItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    inventoryItems.add(Item.hammer);
    inventoryItems.add(Item.tape);
    inventoryItems.add(Item.test);
}
```

This is neither a constructor nor a method for creating an object. It's never used but it seems to serve the purpose of a "static constructor". You should use a static initializer instead to initialize `static` fields:

```
public final static ArrayList<Item> inventoryItems;

static {
    inventoryItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
    inventoryItems.add(Item.hammer);
    inventoryItems.add(Item.tape);
    inventoryItems.add(Item.test);
}
```

Furthermore there's a unhealthy mix of `static` data and non-static methods accessing it in the `ItemsManager` class. I'd recommend using a proper

#### mainController class

```
@FXML
public static ComboBox stocks = new ComboBox();
```

fxml elements are not injected to static fields. Therefore the field should be changed to this:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox stocks;
```

Also I recommend using a non-static `options` field or one initialized in a `static` initializer since loading the scene multiple times currently results in the same items being added over and over again.

Moreover if you want to keep the `ItemManager.inventoryItems` field `static` the `im` field is unnecessary you only use `static` members of the class which is bad practice and also unnecessary since you can use the class name instead of the instance:

```
public void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 0; i < ItemManager.inventoryItems.size(); i++) {
        options.add(ItemManager.inventoryItems.get(i).getName());
    }
    stocks.setItems(options);
}
```